# Error resolving symbol values statically- Angular 4

Tags: angular

Hi I have extended http and this is my module:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: HttpService,
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) => {
        return new HttpService(backend, options);
      },
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
```

The first 'ng serve' give me this error:

> Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls
>   are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda w ith a
>   reference to an exported function

But compilation is successful after I just press Ctrl + S to a file again without changing anything.
What I have to change in my module to solve this "casual" error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the AOT compiler complaining about the [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (lambda). `() => {}`. Try changing this.

```
useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) => {
    return new HttpService(backend, options);
},
```

**To this:**

```
deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions],
useFactory(backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
   return new HttpService(backend, options);
},
```

Here is a helpful article about this. https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5

**Related:**

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13614

Comment: Thanks a lot but  why AOT have this issue with lambda?

Comment: @Alessandro, To be honest I am not entirely sure myself. I think it might be a bug. Which is why I think this ticket https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13614 is still be open.

Comment: I don't know why but still have this error and I don't have any lambda